# Magento store custom object in cache for speeding up site

Tags: php

Hi I want to store my object in cache. How can do this

Please check below example.

```
public function getMyCollection () {


    $cacheKey = 'DIRECTORY_FEATURES_PRODUCT_STORE_' . Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
    if (Mage::app()->useCache('config') && $cache = Mage::app()->loadCache($cacheKey)) 
    {

        $options = unserialize($cache);
    } else 
    {
        $options = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image', 'short_description'), 'inner')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('news_from_date')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('news_to_date')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('special_price')
        ->setPageSize(8)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array(2, 3, 4))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->catId()));



        if (Mage::app()->useCache('config')) {
            Mage::app()->saveCache(serialize($test), $cacheKey, array('config'));

        }
    }
    return $options;

    //return $this->products;
}
```

BUT ITS not working. I want to speed up my home page and feature product take 4 second to load but if I disable the feature slider it take 0.7 second to load the home.

can you please guide me what I have to do.